# Android How To hide/show some view when keyboard show/hide?

Tags: android, view, keyboard

[image: keyboard hide]
[image: keyboard show]

just like the picture, when the keyboard is show ,it hide the logo.

the question is how to listen the keyboard show/hide even? have some sample?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/3514144

Comment: I think this may be help http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#isAcceptingText()

Comment: http://felhr85.net/2014/05/04/catch-soft-keyboard-showhidden-events-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to the layout which you want to hide when keyboard pops up. You can set the visibility of that to `GONE` when keyboard is shown and to `VISIBLE` otherwise. So your task now is to detect whether the keyboard is shown or hidden. For that you can use `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()`.

```
rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);

                int screenHeight = rootView.getHeight();
                int keyboardHeight = screenHeight - (rect.bottom - rect.top);
                if(keyboardHeight > screenHeight / 3){
                    //hide the layout
                }
                else{
                    //show the layout
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

add this attribute to your activity in manifest

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```